# How to setup irods on EC2 instance

Tags: linux

I'm using the EC2-server to setup iRODS on my server, but every time i try to setup the iRODS I get this message:

```
**Configuration problem:
    Cannot copy the Postgres configuration template file:
        File:  /home/ec2-user/iRODS/config/installPostgres.config.template
    Permissions problem?  Missing file?**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably a permissions problem, as the installPostgres.config.template file is part of the distribution file (irods3.3.tgz or other).  Since iRODS servers run as non-root, the irodssetup script is designed to install Postgres in a user accessible directory (which is handy for testing).

You might find some useful information and links on our EC2 page on iRODS.org:
https://www.irods.org/index.php/EC2

A good way to get help on iRODS post questions on the irod-chat google group.

Wayne Schroeder, iRODS Developer